# PHP $_SESSION variables lifetime on server

Tags: php, session

Okay, so I know that the default time session variables last on a server is 1440 seconds or 24 minutes. Then what is the purpose of the variables if they just vanish as garbage? Does this mean my user gets logged out every 24 minutes because the session variables are renewing? Is it wise for me to change the session.gc_maxlifetime to something like 2 weeks, so that the user can stay logged in for two weeks? This is all terribly confusing, so I would appreciate any kind of help in advance!

Comment: y u not use cookies? http://gurflob.com/storage/pics/YUNO/YUNO.png

Comment: I was not sure if session variables did what cookies do in a smoother fashion, but it appears that is not the case. Back to the cookie board and database queries!

Comment: This would take you 25 mins of your life to learn in the hard way - to test your website by yourself, if you were actually logged out after 24 mins

Comment: @RoyalBg that's poor advice, because any conclusions from such a test would be incorrect. session garbage collection is probability based, and also commonly subject to influence from other scripts and virtual hosts on the same server.

Comment: @chris someone you mentioned was not suggested anything, he just explain how op wasted his time. read the first line of the question, thanks

Comment: Yes, I was confused, because I was able to use the session variables method and not be logged out until about 24 hours went by or I closed the browser. It seems I just was not clear on the actual purpose of sessions in php, but all of your answers helped shed some light! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the point of a session. The session usually persist until the user closes the browser (which is the point the browser deletes the session cookie by default). Leaving the session open for 2 weeks means that if the user forgets to log out, someone else may open the page and be logged in.

The session is alive 24 minutes (or whatever the setting is) from the last user interaction with the page. If you are using ajax, the ajax calls themselves will extend the session, so the user won't be logged out while the page is open in the browser.

The "remember me" or "keep me logged in" feature is something completely different and it usually sets another cookie (which may expire in 2 weeks) with some token and automatically logging in the user and starting a new session. Well you can actually persist the session in the database and restoring the same session.

Just keep in mind that the session relies on a cookie in the user's browser, and this cookie usually is a short-lived one.

Answer (score 2):

It's apparently not so confusing, because you're right: the sessions expire after that amount of time (or when the user closes the browser) and changing that setting will affect the lifetime of the session store on the server. Of course, every time the user visits a page the time is set to 24 minutes again.

But if you really want long-term storage, use a **database or cookies**. You really shouldn't use sessions for that, because they're just *sessions* (in English that means one visit to the site, so until the user closes your site).

Comment: thanks that was the answer I was looking for. I plan to use a database instead. I was confused about the purpose of sessions

Comment: -1 sessions don't have an expiration. they *may* be garbage collected after a minimum period of inactivity.

Comment: @chris That's more of an implementation detail than a general rule. For example, if you were to use the `memcache` session store instead of `file` they will expire after exactly 24 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is simple storage session in databes http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/taking-control-of-your-php-sessions-using-database-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout for the session variable , but it will create unnecessary problems for your app. still if you want to set timeout:

To set a one minute timeout on a session, you could call the above function like so:

```
session_start_timeout(60);
```